# Safari jittering/jumping (bug?) on first "focus" event of page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, webkit, css-animations

I'm currently fighting a very frustrating bug on Safari, and I'm not sure where else to turn.

It seems **most** elements (but not all, and I can't discern the differentiating factor) that will trigger a `focus` event will cause all elements on the page that are transitioned or animated to jump ~2px to the top and left. And this only occurs on the first focus event after the page loads.

It's a little annoying to see the bug, as it's in the logged-in portion of [droplr.com](http://droplr.com), and I have been completely unable to distill down a simpler case on JSFiddle.

If you have/create an account and log-in, click on this edit icon for a drop:

[image]

You'll see that on the first focus of the page, things jitter. Here's the timeline when there's a single drop on the page and I trigger focus on an offending element:

[image]

With more drops, it's just more of the same, but it seems to max out around 40 paints. And the profiler doesn't suggest anything nefarious. Just a trip through jQuery internals.

If instead of laying elements out via a `translate3d` or `matix3d`, I simply use `top` and `left`, this bug goes away. After hours and hours of debugging this, I'm at a complete loss.

Hoping someone has seen something similar, could take a look, or could give me advice on debugging next steps.

Thanks so much!

**Update:** Dave Desandro [suggested](https://twitter.com/desandro/status/185374895167913984) it was the 3d acceleration kicking in, so I tried it out with a `translate` instead, and sure enough, that did not cause the jitter. I have no idea why the hardware acceleration would be firing up with a `focus` event though, and only once.

I've tried setting a transformZ of 0 on page load to go ahead and ramp-up the hardware, but no luck there, either. Any more ideas are welcomed.

Comment: What's you Safari version? Just checked on Safari 5.1.4 - seems fine.

I am aware of several bugs with webkit related to animation and transforms, but they are related to the text rendering/antialiazing, not matrix position;

Comment: Interesting, I'm on 5.1.4 as well, and I know it's happening on 5.2.

Comment: Have you tried  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; on those elements? Give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately hiding the backface visibility didn't help, either.

Comment: you said that the elements which jitter are styled with transitions or animations. Are you using -webkit-transition: all ? or are you only specifying the transitions that you need?

Comment: If you're seeing this on fonts, maybe adding   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; would help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue a while back and honestly I don't remember what exactly was the cause but here are some of the steps I followed:

Check that you don't have hide() and show() for the same element in the next line or vice versa.
Example:
el.show()
el.hide()

Change Custom fonts to "Arial"

For the elements you don't want focus events add this code at the bottom of your scripts:
`noFocusElem.off('focus');`
This will make sure to remove any focus handlers you might have added by mistake

Finally place your css before any scripts. It's a know fact that adding css rules after an inline style has been applied may cause jitter especially if you're using line-hieght property

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen when using custom font kits. Could this be the issue? Some events cause custom fonts to re-draw, which can cause a ever so slight "jitter" in page display.

Sometimes, manually setting heights and widths on all the parent HTML elements can reduce the flicker.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was posted a while ago and this is a bit of a long shot but here goes:

Maybe as a starting point go back to chrome and look at the composite layering:

Hit this into the address bar:
about:flags

You will be able to enable composite borders from within there. The red borders generally indicate a rendering issue:

http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome

What I have found from time to time is that although there are rendering issues in Chrome the browser copes pretty well with hiding them from me. In other webkit based browsers however the result can be more noticable (i.e. android).

I've also seen flickering occur when z-indexes are being used in conjunction with content that is being transformed.

Either way it would be great to know how you resolved this issue (if you did). Post an answer to your own question perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

A way to avoid spending time fixing load time twitches; you could set the page to hidden then make elements visible with the load.  If your page is slow to load, you may want to have a spinner default to visible, then  have load hide it.  Then you could come back to the issue when you have nothing better to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2c worth.

**The first thing I would try:**
First in chrome, whack in 'about:flags' (yes I know you're not using Chrome). Find the 'Composited render layer borders' and turn it on. Once this feature is switched on you'll get a rough idea of what is being rendered/hardware accelerated.

See: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome

and look for any rendering problems. These are normally caused by z-indexes. Play around with any z-indexes and hide/show certain elements until the rendering issues are resolved. Then work from there. translate-z hacks and opacity can also cause problems.

From experience I've found rendering problems in other webkit browsers can be diagnosed using chrome. Flickering is a common occurrence on the stock android browser.

**Secondly:** take a look at the focus event itself and try things like preventing the default behaviour. Seems like a long shot to me but give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, so I will be very surprised if it works... but here's an idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).focus(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
      $(document).unbind();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into the same issue recently and found something that fixed it in my case.

Check for anything that's hidden offscreen like:

```
text-indent: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
```

Removing any instance of these from the 3d accelerated elements (including children) stopped the content jump on focus for me.